# AZURE: Cannot clear the Query Store

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to setup the Automatic Tuning for the Azure SQL Database, but I have found out the "Query Store is in read-only state" [image]

So I plan to use the command to clear it to make it run **"ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB] SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR"**, but it got the error[image]

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Please be aware that if you have a very ad hoc workload you can overload the space in the database that the query store uses.  So, simply clearing it may not solve your actual problem.  You may need to adjust what gets captured to be more selective or consider more aggressive query parameterization if you have many similar query text shapes.  I suggest you work on determining this before clearing out the query store.  You can use the query store data itself to help give you an idea of what is taking space. It will clean up after itself in normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

To set the query store to read write mode use

```
ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]
SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE);
```

But your error code 615 means that the cache is not in sync with the database, due to connection problems.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql

Check that your SQL Server database is online

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have set it to the read and write mode, but still shows the same error when I try to clear the query store.

Answer (score 0):

Tho the SQL command does not work, I found that there is a button that can help me finish the job -> Purge Query Data button at the right down corner.
[image]